# How can I make my table cell UITextField editable when the table has entered 'edit' mode?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a simple table view which is editable. All I need the user to be able to do is edit the text field in the cell when they choose to edit the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell to make it editable inline. The default implementation just contains UILabels, which are not editable. For example, if you had a UITextField view in your cell, you'd override `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` and make the text field become the first responder.