# iOS Development: How can I cause a UITableViewCell to change into an editable UITextField when it's tapped?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, ios5

I have a grouped `UITableView` and one of the cells displays the name of person.  I'd like to allow the user to edit the name of the person when they tap on the cell.  The only way I know to do this is to add a `UITextField` to the `cell`, the only problem is it looks ugly when it's ALWAYS a `UITextField`.  I'd prefer to have the `cell` display the name of the person like a `UILabel` and when it's tapped, somehow transform it into a `UITextField` where it can be edited.  Then when the person taps the return key on the keyboard, transform it back to a `UILabel`. Is this possible?

I did a search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554714/how-can-i-make-my-table-cell-uitextfield-editable-when-the-table-has-entered-ed) asked, but the selected answer was so vague that I couldn't understand the solution.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it looks ugly". You can make a UITextField clear so that it would appear exactly like a UILabel when it is not tapped on. Can you maybe post a picture of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextFieldBorderStyleNone;
```

and voilà - it looks like a `UILabel`!

Comment: You may have to adjust the cell layout after toggling the border style.

Comment: thanks, that worked well. I also had to set the background color to clear, as jamie suggested "addressTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];"